# Gitflow branching strategy

Tags: git, maven, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

First of all, I know very well about Gitflow, and try to push my team to follow it completely. However, operation team only allows to release the application version that QA certified. If we follow Gitflow, the release version should always come from master branch, but since QA tests release branch, they only certifies release candidates. In order to have QA certify master cut, they need to run another regression test which is why they are pushing back. All the release candidates have RC# in the version which is not good maven versions following major.minor.patch pattern.

My question is how to avoid extra regression test after merging release into master, before production release? Any advices are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`master` represents what is currently in production.  In gitflow you create a `release` branch off of develop.   QA would then test the `release` branch.  Once QA is happy, the `release` branch is deployed and then merged to `master`.

There should be nothing to test when you merge a `release` branch to `master`.  It's already been tested.

But what's important is whenever `master` is updated (by merging in release branches), you also need to merge `master` into `develop`.  This way when you cut the next `release` branch from `develop` you know it has all of the code that has been deployed.

Comment: that makes sense, and we are doing the same as you described